# Does a Jew named after a respected historical figure need to hold himself to a higher standard of behavior?

Tags: names, sin, tzibur-community

This question may sound strange but it relates to the power of names on Judaism.

Typically, when a Jew is named after respected figures from Jewish history, it's done because we hope for our children to live up to the characteristics of such individuals.

- The humbleness of Moses
- The faith of Abraham
- The beauty of Esther
- etc.

That being said, people are human and they don't always live up to the names they are given. Some even go in the opposite direction in certain cases.

My question is simple. If a Jew is named after respected individuals, can it be argued that they have to be careful in how they act because their mistakes are simultaneously tainting the name they share with such respected figures?

If someone named Moses does something terrible and they are seen in the community as having done something terrible, does the fact they share Moshe Rabbeinu's name inadvertently cast an insult on the person they're named after?

Comment: Live up to the beauty of Esther? How can one work on that? And is that really her best quality??

Comment: I knew a Yehoshua who was more sun than moon. It caused him him great consternation.

Comment: “Can it be argued...” - from a halachic perspective? Otherwise it can certainly be argued.

Comment: Maybe so, and maybe that would explain the rarity of certain Biblical names (such as Avraham, Moshe, David) in the Talmudic era - maybe people were afraid that giving their child such names would set too high a bar for them?

Comment: @DoubleAA Beauty isn't merely a physical thing. It also relates to how one carries themselves and their spiritual aspects on top of that. A person can most certainly develop beauty within the characteristics under their control. It isn't purely a matter of looks.

Comment: @Avri and why would one associate Esther specifically with that sort of metaphorical beauty? Why wouldn't you pick "courage" or "self-sacrifice" or "leadership"?

Comment: I recently researched the concept of naming children, but the source are not directly related to this question (because it's not true). I've posted it as a separate [question and answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105681/naming-your-baby-does-the-name-influence-the-child); see Minchas Elazar quoted there, which is the closest to the assertion in the question.

Comment: THis is from abovementioned Chortkov's answer: וע״כ נהגו לקראו על שם הצדיקים גם מטעם זה כדי להיות מסוגל להזכיר זכות צדקתם שיהיה הבן הנולד מוצלח בתורה ויר״א ובכל עניניו וילך בדרכיהם, וגם כשידע שהוא נקרא על שמותם אולי יעורר א״ע פעמים להתבייש מלצאת חוץ לגדר כ״כ ויזכור להתדבק במעשי אבותיו או רבותיו הקודמים אבל לא שיכריחו ע״ז להעתקת הנפש בע״כ להבן הנולד,

Comment: Please do not start a question with "can it be argued, that" as it turns it into opinions and should be closed. We should try to formulate the title without biases or prejudices.

Comment: I don't know how many kids you named but your assertion that "*Typically, when a Jew is named ... we hope for our children to live up to the characteristics of such individuals.*" isn't realistic. It's 80% family and 20% social pressure and 0.05% Tzaddik's qualities. IMHO of course.