# Naming your baby - does the name influence the child?

Tags: names, mysticism-kabbalah, children-parenting

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105672/can-it-be-argued-that-a-jew-named-after-a-respected-historical-figure-needs-to-h): Is there any significance to the name you choose to give your child? Does the name have any influence over the child? Is there any reason to choose to name your son after someone specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96342/discussion-between-al-berko-and-chortkov2).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73

Answer (score 7):

The earliest source that a name has an intrinsic influence on the child is the Midrash Tanchuma:

> זכור ימות עולם בינו שנות דור ודור: לעולם יבדוק אדם בשמות לקרוא לבנו
>   הראוי להיות צדיק, **כי לפעמים השם גורם טוב או גורם רע**, כמו שמצינו
>   במרגלים... - מדרש תנחומא האזינו ז

A similar concept is found in Yuma 83b, where R' Meir assessed peoples character by judging their names:

> ר' מאיר הוה דייק בשמא... אמר ש"מ אדם רשע

The source for the influence of the names is expounded in Brachos 7b:

> **מנא לן דשמא גרים** אמר רבי אליעזר דאמר קרא לכו חזו מפעלות ה׳ אשר שם שמות בארץ 
>   אל תקרי שמות אלא שמות

The Sefer Chassidim (244) writes lengthily on the concept, and advises on numerous applications:

> . **ועוד אומר דברים שהשם גורם לטובה או לרעה לטובה** יש אדם שכל הנקראין
>   בשמו יצליחו לגדולה זהו ויקרא בהם שמי ושם אבותי. וכתיב כי כאשר השמים
>   החדשים והארץ החדשה אשר אני עושה עומדים לפני אמר ה' כן יעמוד זרעכם
>   ושמכם. וכתיב קראתי בשמך לי אתה. הרי שיש אדם שכל אותם הנקראים על שמו
>   יחיו ויהיו בניו קיימי' ויעמידו תולדות ויש שכל אלה להם להפך שנאמר
>   והנחתם שמכם לשבועה לבחירי והמיתך ה' ולעבדיו יקרא שם אחר וכתיב והכרתי
>   לבבל שם ושאר ונין ונכד, וכתיב ׳לא נין ולא נכד בעמו ואין שריד במגוריו׳.
>   וכתיב ׳ולא שם לו על פני חוץ׳. **לכן יתפלל אדם שכל הנקראים בשמו יהיו בהם
>   מדות טובות האלה ולא אחת מן המדות הרעות ושלא יקראו זרעו על אותן שמדות
>   הרעות תלויות בהן**. כיצד יראה אדם כשיש שני אחי' וקראו שם בניהם ובנותיהם
>   אחר שם פלוני אפילו אחר צדיק ומתו בלא תולדות. או שהיו הכתובים למעלה
>   לרעה בהם אל יקראו יותר באותו השם ר"ל שקראו לו שם בגורל מתוך הספר כאשר
>   עושין לחולה או בשני אחים נתקיים למאן דאמר שנים לחזקה ולמאן דאמר שלשה
>   לחזקה פעמים שהאחים קוראים בשם אותו האיש ונכשלים זרעו או האחים קראו את
>   בניהם אחר אביהם ומתו והבנות קראו בניהן וחיו ויש שם פלוני שכל המשפחה
>   שלו אם קראו זרעם בשמם מתו בלא תולדות ולא האריכו ימיהם ובכל ענינים האלו
>   לנקבות ובשם שיראה החכם שכך הוא אל יאמר אקיים לאבותי שם שלא ישכח והוא
>   רואה שנקראים אחרים ונכשלו הרי הוא נושא אל נפשו עון. ואין אלו הדברים
>   משום ניחוש שהרי הראשונים היו קוראים את בניהם על שם המאורע ולא מתו.
>   אא"כ חטאו בער ואונן לכך יהיו צדיקים שזרעם מתים ולא מחמת עון. אלא שאלו
>   הדברים הזיקו ואע"פ כן יש לאדם לחשוב שמא בעונו הוא וכל שמתים בניו
>   ואחרים קראו אחר פלוני וזה קראו כמו כן ומתו הרי נגזר עליו לפי שכינו
>   אחרים שם כמוה.

The Poskim ([R' Moshe Feinstien](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=192) based on Yam Shel Shlomo [Gittin 4:31], and [Chasam Sofer EH 2:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Even_HaEzer.2.25.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) caution against naming a child for someone who was 'ריע מזליה' - a man of misfortune, or who died young (R' Elyashiv and R' Yackov Kaminetzky set the boundary at someone who died less than 60, the Minchas Yitzchok set it at 50).

However, Bamidbar Rabba (16:10) cautions that this is not an absolute rule:

> יש בני אדם ששמותם נאים ומעשיהם כעורים, שמותם כעורים ומעשיהם נאים,
>   ששמותיהם נאים ומעשיהם נאים, שמותיהם ומעשיהם כעורים

The Maharam Chaviv ([Tosfos Yom Hakipurim, Yuma 83](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14008&st=&pgnum=59)) advises the same:

> דודאי על הרוב השמות מורים על הפעולות ולכן צריך האדם למיחש מיהא כשרואה
>   אדם דשמו מגונה דלמא גם מעשיו מכוערין, **אמנם יש מיעוט בני אדם דאין
>   הולכין פעולותיהם אחר שמותיהם** וכו׳

The Arizal (Sha'ar Hagilgulim, p23) explains that the choosing of the name is not accidental. (See Ben Yehoyada Yuma 38 for three alternative explanations in the Arizal's word)

> כאשר נולד האדם, וקוראים לו אביו ואמו שם אחד העולה בדעתם, **אינו באקראי
>   ובהזדמן כי אם הקב״ה משים בפיו שהם ההוא המוכרח אל הנשמה ההיא**, כמש״ה אשר
>   שם שמות בארץ כפי מקום האבר שבאדם העליון, אשר ממנו חוצב, והשם הזה נרשם
>   למעלה בכסא הכבוד כנודע, ולכן ארז״ל שמא גרים.

The Teshuras Shai (§5) writes that when calling a name, it creates a certain connection to the soul of the deceased (and therefore cautions against calling after someone who has not yet been buried).

> נראה לי דאין לקרות שם תינוק על שם המת שלא נקבר עדיין לפמ״ש הזהר וכן
>   הוא ברקנטי פ׳ תצא וכו׳  הרי **דיש בזה העתקה מנפש המת לזה הנקרא בשמו**, כי
>   נפש חיה הוא שמו ועי׳ אה״ח פרשת פנחס בפסוק ושם איש ישראל וא״כ לא יתכן
>   להעתיק השם מהראשון לאחר כל זמן שלא נקבר גוף הראשון

The Minchas Elozor ([V4, §27](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1862&st=&pgnum=58)) vehemently opposes this notion, and writes that there is no connection created between the newborn and the deceased, but simply a *zechus* by mentioning the righteousness of the deceased *tzaddik*, and 'perhaps this will inspire the child to be ashamed to act in a way that does not live up to his name, and he will remember to emulate the acts of his ancestors' (loose translation):

> **והני מילי סתראי מופרכים וסותרים מעיקרא** ממ״ש כנזכר דקריאת השם הוי העתקת
>   הנפש מהמת לפי שנקרא בשמו. **וזה אינו ברור ולא הביא שום ראיה מוכחת שיש בה
>   ממש**. דממ״ש היש״ש בגיטיל בקריאת שם ישעי׳ דלא מסמנא מילתא היינו משום
>   שהנביא ישעי׳ הרגו בן בנו עיי״ש בודאי אין ראיה, דז״א רק כעין סימנא
>   מילתא למזל הבן. דאם נאמר שנעתק הנפש להנולד ע״י קריאת השם אדרבה מה טוב
>   היה אם יוכלו להמשיך הנפש הקדוש של הנביא ישעיהו בתוך הבן הנולד וכן מכל
>   הצדיקים אם יקראו מהמון את שמות ביניהם בשמם וכי ימשכו ויעתיקו בע״כ את
>   נשמותיהם להנולד שיקראוהו בשמם אם יהיה מי שיהיה בין פחותי ערך הגרעוים,
>   **ולכולם בודאי לא ניתנו הדברים להאמר כלל לכל בר דעה**. וכן ממה שהביא שם
>   דאחז״ל רשעים לא אסקינן בשמייהו רקביבות תעלה בשמותן בודאי אין שום סרך
>   ראיה כלל, ממילא ג״כ אין ראיה לזה כלל ממ״כ שם בשם האוה״ח פ׳ פנחס עיי״ש.
>   ועיין ברמב״ן (וישב לח-ח) מה שחולק על רש״י בכתוב ׳והקם זרע לאחיך׳
>   שפירש״י הבן יקרא על ם המת, וע״ז פליג הרמב״ן וצווח דהרי במצות התורה
>   נאמר ג״כ יקום על שם אחיו המת ולא ימחה שמו מישראל ואעפ״כ אין היבם מצווה
>   לקראו לבנו כשם אחיו עיי״ש. ובאמת היא ש״ס ערוכה ביבמות (כ״ד.) דדרשינן
>   ׳יקום על שם אחיו המת – אתה אומר לנחלה או אינו אלא לשם, יוסף קורין אותו
>   יוסף, יוחנן קורין אותו יוחנן, נאמר כאן יקום על שם אחיו ונאמר להלן על
>   שם אחיהם יקראו בנחלתם מה להלן נחלה אף שם האמור כאן לנחלה וכו׳ אמר רבא
>   אע״ג דבכל התורה אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו הכא אתאי גזירה שוה אפיקתיה
>   מפשטותיה לגמרי׳, פירש״י ׳שאין צריך לקרות לבנו בשם אחיו המת׳ עכ״ל. וא״כ
>   ביבום שאין לך יותר העתקה וטובת הנפש להמת מע״י יבום והבן שיוליד לאחיו
>   היבם בחיבור נפשו כמ״ש המפרשים הראשונים ומקובלים ואעפ״כ פסקינן בזה
>   בפירוש שאין שום סמך ופי׳ לקרוא להבן הנולד על שם המת ואין לך השגה גדולה
>   מזו. **והרי דקריאת השם אינו גורם העתקת הנפש להנולד**. אלא הוא **ודאי דמה
>   שקורין בשם הצדיקים הוא לזכר וכבוד הצדיקים**, וכדאמרינן במדרש רבה (וירא
>   פמ״ט) עיי״ש, וכהאי דדרז״ל בברכות (ז:) בקריאת שם ראובן ראובן מה בין בני
>   לבן חמי וכו׳ וכן כיוצא וכן במד״ר שלח לענין קריאת שמות המרגלים, והיינו
>   דהוא סגוליות והשם ג״כ גורם במעשי האדם ועניניהם, **וע״כ נהגו לקראו על שם
>   הצדיקים גם מטעם זה כדי להיות מסוגל להזכיר זכות צדקתם שיהיה הבן הנולד
>   מוצלח בתורה ויר״א ובכל עניניו וילך בדרכיהם, וגם כשידע שהוא נקרא על
>   שמותם אולי יעורר א״ע פעמים להתבייש מלצאת חוץ לגדר כ״כ ויזכור להתדבק
>   במעשי אבותיו או רבותיו הקודמים אבל לא שיכריחו ע״ז להעתקת הנפש בע״כ
>   להבן הנולד**, וכיון שהוא רק לזכר הצדיקים או אבותיו לכבודם ולסגולת זכות
>   צדקתם א״כ אין נ״מ אם נקראותו לשמו קודם קבורת המת או לאחריו וכו

Comment: One (minor) chronological point: R. Eliezer (b. Hurkanas), quoted in your citation of Brachos 7b, predates the Midrash Tanchuma.

Answer (score 4):

The Talmud in [Yoma 38b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=38b&format=pdf) tells us that we do not name children after wicked people. It brings a story about a boy named Doeg who was killed and eaten by his mother. The Talmud says that this was because he was named after a wicked person.

Rabbeinu Chananel there says that someone who is named after a wicked person will not succeed in life.

See the sources in [Ziv HaShemos 25:1 footnote 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53094&pgnum=86)

Comment: Good addition to the influence on the child's behaviour.